# Underscore Template with Ruby Backend not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, underscore.js

I am using the underscore template to create a template for making bootstrap dropdown menus. The code worked fine on my own computer, but now I'm adding it to a ruby on rails backend server. Now the code no longer works. I was told the code in between the <% %> is interpreted as ruby code instead of javascript. I don't know ruby at all, but someone showed me how to write a for loop.

```
<!-- Dropdown Menu-->
<script type="text/template" id="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span> <%= name %> </span>
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <% array_of_items.each do |obj| %>
          <li> <a> <%= obj %> </a> </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</script>
```

The error I get is "Undefined variable array_of_items" Of course it's not defined, I define it later on

```
this.$el.append(this.makeDropdown({
    name: this.name,
    array_of_items: [1,2,3,4]
}));
```

The underscore template works like this for Javascript, but for Ruby it will not allow me to have an undefined variable in a template for some reason, What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem I think is here:

```
<% array_of_items.each do |obj| %>
```

Rails is interpreting this as ERB, and as there's no variable declared in Ruby, you're getting the error. Try adding your JS code into the asset pipeline perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's and ruby's variable are in quite different 'scopes';
here `<% array_of_items %>` should be defined as a template local variable:

```
<% array_of_items = [1,2] %>
<%= array_of_items %>
<script>
  document.body.innerHTML += array_of_items;
  array_of_items = ['j', 's'];
  document.body.innerHTML += array_of_items;
  // var from js + var from ruby
  document.body.innerHTML += array_of_items + <% array_of_items %>; // #=> should be smth like `js12`
</script>
```

Comment: is there a way to declare the variable inside the template and replace it with

this.$el.append(this.makeDropdown({
    name: this.name,
    array_of_items: [1,2,3,4]
}));

Instead, I am getting the default array [1,2] instead of [1,2,3,4].